# Customized reactive search with Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am new to Meteor and am having trouble with the following. I need to implement reactive search with multiple collections and multiple fields/$and selector. Any kind of guidance will be much appreciated.

The app should use the 4/5 collections and then based on 3 text-filters (DB fields) and the collection choice (from a drop down menu), return reactive results.So, let's say, from the drop down , they select collection c1 and then type in the following - for field f1, 11, for field f2, 22, f3, 33.

Now the app should return documents from c1 that have the respective values {f1:11, f2:22...} for the 3 fields.
The query will be something like:
`collection.find({$and: [{f1:11, f2:22, f3:33...}]})`

What I have been trying so far.

## Route 1

[aldeed/meteor-autoform](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform)

Using autoform, I have developed a form with the drop down and textboxes. I am not sure how to proceed from here - how to integrate, say easy-search with autoform.

## Route 2

[matteodem/easy-search](https://atmospherejs.com/matteodem/easy-search)

Just easy-search. I am still working on developing the reactive search using just this package. I am following the leaderboard example there. Being in dev phase, I don't know what else I will need to know.

## Route 3

[aslagle/reactive-table](https://atmospherejs.com/aslagle/reactive-table)

Using reactive-table. I have it working with the default filter. The reactive results come out fine. Now I am trying to customize the filter but it's not working. Not sure what I am doing wrong - helpers.js or the template. Or, if I need to integrate something else-like, easy-search, given the complexity of the query.

Please let me know what code parts you need and I'll add it in my edit. (Adding everything would make it too long).

Answer (score 1):

With EasySearch, you can define your own special queries.

```
EasySearch.createSearchIndex('cars', {
  'field' : ['name', 'price'],
  'collection' : Cars,
  'limit' : 20,
  'query' : function (searchString, opts) {
    var query = EasySearch.getSearcher(this.use).defaultQuery(this, searchString);
    query.$and = query.$and || {};
    // do whatever you need with `$and` here
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice answer. So its possible to have multiple input fields on the client and show results per entries with that method right (if I modify, obviously)? IE: If I have a Posts collection with tags, categories, author and if I fill 3 input fields for each collection field, it will search the posts containing those files right? Thanks (:

Comment: Or is it better to write my own search with custom input fields which will get the values from input fields and return with Posts.find?